# How can I strip a subdomain if it is "www" in a Rails 3.2 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, subdomain

I have a Rails 3.2 application that is driven by subdomains:

```
company1.myapp.com
companyn.myapp.com
```

Some people are trying to do this:

```
www.companyn.myapp.com
```

Which yields an error. How can I strip out that leading subdomain if it's www?

I have this in my app controller:

```
def redirect_to_subdomain_page
  subdomain = request.subdomain
  subdomain = "xyz" if subdomain.blank? or subdomain=="www"
  render "#{subdomain}_#{params[:action]}"
end
```

But if they go to `www.companyn.myapp.com` I want to redirect them to just `companyn.myapp.com`. I want to redirect them so the actual URL changes.

Comment: you likely have some code in your application_controller that finds an object based on your subdomain --- can you post that here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.subdomains` should return an array of all subdomains so you could do something like:

```
def redirect_to_subdomain_page
  subdomains = request.subdomains
  if subdomains.length <= 1
    subdomain = subdomains.first
    subdomain = "xyz" if subdomain.blank? or subdomain=="www"
    render "#{subdomain}_#{params[:action]}"
  else
    redirect_to "http://companyn.myapp.com/#{request.fullpath}"
  end
end
```

Comment: request.subdomains is the missing piece of the puzzle, thanks jokklan!

Answer (score 1):

You can unburden your Rails app by having your NGINX or Apache server redirect to the non-www version before ever touching your app.